# My application works on android emulator but don't work in android device

Tags: android, web-services, socket-timeout-exception

I made a web service in .Net Framework 3.5 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and called it from android. I used Sql Server as a database.

When I am running my application in the android emulator, it will run fine but if I install it onto my android device, then it will throw a java.socket.SocketTimeOutException.

Comment: Please provide explicit info such as logcat of that Exception?

Comment: Dear ss12712,
I mentioned that my application successfully run on the android emulator but it don't successfully run on the Android Device. How can i provide you the logcat of that exception..??
In android device it gives java.net.SocketTimeout Exception

Comment: do you have Android SDK installed? It contains a tool called DDMS, run it, it will produce the logcat. Or just use Eclipse with ADT plugin, it will do the same.

Comment: Dear ss1271,
Actually what happens my code is running on Android emulator i.e. Android SDK runs very good. But it's failed in the Android Device. I installed my application in my friends laptop then it will run very good in both Android Emulator as well as android mobile. But in the case of my laptop it will work in Android Emulator but failed in Android Mobile.

Comment: Yeah, but it will be good if you can provide some kind of log output, that would help you and us to figure out the reason why it failed. :)

Comment: How can I provide you the detail of error available in logcat if my application does not omit an error while running on emulator..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Please take care that your computer Firewall is off when you use IIS as virtual server on your local pc. If you turn off your firewall protection then it will be allowed you to access the web methods but if firewall is on then you get java.net.SocketTimeOutException

Answer (score 1):

Is your server running on your desktop from Visual Studio? If so, you cant connect to it from any machine but that particular desktop unless you forward ports or use a proxy server (also on the same machine).